# How to replace <xml> </xml> with empty space

Tags: javascript, regex, xml

I have a xml data, I want to replace the xml data with empty string

I want to replace   with empty string, what is the regular expression to achieve this?

Comment: I am new to this regular expression, any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: you have to search for `<xml>` and `</xml>` and replace that with an empty string ; also calling `trim` will ensure there are no trailing spaces ; no need for regexp here (at least for the simple example you provided some minutes ago ; now the example is gone... not sure what you are up to)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054698/extract-the-specific-substring-from-variable-value#comment106211328_60054698

Answer (score 0):

```js
xmlString = xmlString.toString().replace(/<\/?xml>/gi,"").trim();
```

Comment: this works fine :)